# Click on the link PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I need to get the ajax data from the website unsing PhantomJS. Data is displayed when you press the link.

```
<div class="show-all-goods"><a href="#">Show all</a></div>
```

Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://dveri.com/catalog/dveri-mezhkomnatnyye/dveri-shponirovannyye/', function() {
  page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
   page.evaluate(function(){
         $('.show-all-goods a').click();
  });

});
console.log(page.content);
phantom.exit();
});
```

But the data are not loaded. Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show the data using the line `console.log(page.content);` you are actually calling this function even before the click happens.

Think asynchronous.

The click is executed after the page loads and the js is injected and you can never know when is that going to happen depending on server, network lag etc.

Unfortunately, PhantomJS does not have API for Ajax callbacks.

So far what I had done for similar situations is writing an observer to constantly monitor one or more HTML elements which are affected by the ajax callback. Say for instance, there's a div which is blank now and the ajax callback is going to fill that with some content. I created a `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in PhantomJS code and called `evaluate` which in turn observed any changes in that div. From that evaluate function I returned a boolean based on what I got and took further steps. However, you can also return the content instead which you can put in your `console.log` and then quit the application.

This can be done easily if you use `casperJS` (http://casperjs.org/) using one of the many APIs like `wait()`
`waitFor()`
`waitForResource()`
`waitForSelector()`
`waitWhileSelector()`
`waitForSelectorTextChange()`
`waitForText()`
`waitUntilVisible()`
`waitWhileVisible()`